# T4 Templates(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.14.0) - How can I get custom utility methods to work in VS2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, t4

I've seen many questions related to this topic but none that seem to work for my test project. I am using VS2015 and Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.14.0.  I have followed a tutorial from Pluralsight that is for Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.10.0 I'm not sure that make a huge difference. Considor this I have a solution with 2 projects one is a class library that contains a simple TextTransformation method:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating;
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

namespace CustomDataGenerator
{
    public class CustomDataMethods : TextTransformation
    {
        public string ToTitleCase(string input)
        {
            TextInfo ti = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;
            return ti.ToTitleCase(input.ToLower());
        }
        public override string TransformText()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

The other is a console application.  Both projects reference:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.14.0

and the console application has a reference to the class library project.

> CustomDataGenerator

I added a Text template to the console application configuring it as follows:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" inherits="CustomDataGenerator.CustomDataMethods" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)CustomDataGenerator.dll" #>
    <#= ToTitleCase("HELLO") #>
```

I built the assembly to make sure it exists. Here is the path on my machine:

> C:\Users\Todd.MANCHESTERVILLE\Documents\VSTesting\NewT4Test\NewT4Test\bin\Debug\CustomDataGenerator.dll

and this is the error generated by the text template.:

> Error       Compiling transformation: Metadata file 'C:\Users\Todd.MANCHESTERVILLE\Documents\VSTesting\NewT4Test\NewT4Test\bin\Debug\CustomDataGenerator.dll' could not be found    NewT4Test   C:\Users\Todd.MANCHESTERVILLE\Documents\VSTesting\NewT4Test\NewT4Test\TextTemplate1.tt  1

Here is my full albeit small sample: [Git Repo](https://github.com/toddmanchester/NewT4Test/)

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.  I can't reference the class in the library. I have verified the assembly exists.  Thanks for helping!

**Edit:** I fixed my spelling mistake and added this line:

> <#= ToTitleCase("HELLO") #>

Showing that the custom utility method works. I have updated the [Git Repo](https://github.com/toddmanchester/NewT4Test/)
too.

All is temporarily right in the universe! Except my spelling.

Comment: One is spelled CustomDataGenterator.dll and the other is CustomDataGenerator.dll.

Comment: Hangs head in shame....@Mathemats Thank you very much.  I will update this question with that change and add a small piece that completes the sample.